# click event on a label inside a usercontrol item

Tags: wpf, xaml

hello i am trying to create a click textblock event on a textblock inside a user control ,
with a button it is simple , using the buttonbase property on the main window but here 
i am not sure what to do i will show you my code:
this is my user control:

```
 <Border BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3" Margin="3" >
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Foreground="Blue">Message Number:</Label>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="1">Title:</Label>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="2">Message Date:</Label>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="3">Contact Mail:</Label>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="4">Message Type:</Label>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="5">Message Details:</Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblMessageNum" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblMessageDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblContactMail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblMessageType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblMessageDetails" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"></Label>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock  Margin="23,0,0,0" x:Name="tbkRemove">
                <Underline>Remove Message</Underline>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Border Grid.Row="1"  BorderBrush="Purple" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="3" Margin="23,10,6,0">
                <Image x:Name="ImgPic" Width="102" Height="110"></Image>
            </Border>


        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

inside this usercontrol i got tbkRemove textblock which should have an event to remove it self (the all user control) from the main window so the code of the click event should be on the main window but how can i make such an event
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think I understand the question but not entirely how you want this to be handled. Maybe it would help if you could add some sample code for the Button example that you talked about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i created a new button that looks like a textblock using expression blender so i can bubble it up using buttonbase .